# WSO2ESB Simple Passthrough Proxy doesnt forward the url extensions

Tags: proxy, wso2, wso2-esb

I implemented a simple pass through proxy i.e. when i call

```
   "http://wso2esb:9443/services/proxy"
```

it should forward the request to

```
 "http://destinationserver:80/" .
```

The question is the url extensions are not carried while forwarding.. i.e.

```
  when i do a HTTP POST in       

       http://wso2esb:9443/services/proxy/path1/path2 

  the request is forwarded to 

       http://destinationserver:80 

  rather than to  

        http://destinationserver:80/path1/path2. 

  but HTTP GET behaves as expected. Could anyone  help in where i am going wrong?
```

My Proxy.xml

```
  <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="proxy" transports="https,http"
   statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
     <outSequence>
         <send/>
     </outSequence>
     <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://destinationserver:80/"/>
     </endpoint>
  </target>
  <description/>
</proxy>
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S: my WSO2ESB version : 4.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need that, one way (not sure this is the best) to achieve your goal would be :

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="proxy" transports="https,http"
   statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <header name="To"
                 expression="concat('http://destinationserver:80',substring-after(syn:get-property('To'),'/services/proxy'))"/>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Send a post request to `http://wso2esb:8280/services/proxy/path1/path2` and it should be forwarded to `http://destinationserver:80/path1/path2`

Comment: Thanks Jean. It worked.. but i still want to know why post and get behaved differently on simple pass-through proxy

Answer (score 0):

Things worked as per Jeans answer but Htttp HEAD request is not forwarded except it is returning 400 Bad Request. Testing with direct link on the destination server returns expected response.

Comment: You should have added this as a comment instead of an answer. You may also ask this in WSO2 dev@ mailing list. http://wso2.com/mail/